# How to customize the console colors of GlassFish's errors in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I've came to a point where the console log's colors of GlassFish in Eclipse are annoying me.

Unlike Tomcat that prints errors in red and stacktraces in blue with the possibility to click on a stacktrace element, GlassFish prints everything in black (very ugly formatting).

This of course makes it difficult to quickly debug, it's actually a headache.

So I'm wondering whether there's a way to make the output of GlassFish errors in the Eclipse console look more "beautiful" or at least look like Tomcat's errors.

p.s: I'm using Eclipse Java EE Juno and GlassFish 3.1.2 (server adapter tools installed)

Comment: Window > Preferences > GlassFish Preferences : Enable Colored Rendering in the GlassFish Log viewer.  I have it checked though i see no colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work to 'colorize' any Console log in eclipse.

There is a plugin called [**Grep Console**](http://youtu.be/fXjgGZAxToc) which highlights or colors Console log based on string patterns in the output.

### Update Sites

**Grep Console 2** 
http://eclipse.musgit.com 
(requires Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) or higher and Java 5.0 or higher)

**Grep Console 3** 
http://eclipse.schedenig.name  
(requires Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) or higher and Java 6.0 or higher)

### Usage

Once you have installed the plugin using the Update Site, you should see an icon in the console view which should allow you to add Expressions (regular expressions) against which output in the Console is matched and formatting that you choose (backgroud color, foreground color etc.) is applied.

#### Screencast

Please see **[this](http://youtu.be/fXjgGZAxToc)** screencast which shows the whole process.

#### New version (3.x) released.

I received a comment from the creator of the Grep Console plugin. He mentioned that **Grep console 3 is has been released.** I have added the link to the update site above (take a look at the requirements; if you are on an Eclipse version < 3.7 then you'll need to used v2.x of the Grep Console)

Comment: Just checked the screencast, it's indeed simple and useful. However i'm looking forward more screencasts and tips on how to use it, please send me a link where i can follow more screencasts about this plugin.
I'll leave the door opened till tomorrow for more answers and suggestions, before i check your answer as accepted.